# Android - Como criar uma comparação para que itens da LISTVIEW sejam exibidos ou não de acordo com a data?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, simpledateformat

Estou criando um app que mostrará farmácias abertas em determinada data:
[image: Tela inicial]

Criei uma listview com 10 linhas (as farmácias)...
E de acordo com o dia do mês certas unidades serão exibidas... ou não.
Estou pegando a data atual do aparelho, guardando e exibindo usando :

```
// MOSTRA A DATA ATUAL
        dataatual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataatual);
        long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(date);
        dataatual.setText(dateString);
        // FIM DATA ATUAL
```

Porém, não sei criar uma comparação, seja com if/else, for ou switch (nem sei qual melhor se aplica) para "filtrar" qual linha da listview deve ser apresentada de acordo com a data.

Código inteiro:

```
public class TELA001 extends AppCompatActivity {

static class Data
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        SimpleDateFormat formataData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date data = new Date();
        String dataFormatada = formataData.format(data);
        System.out.println("Data formatada " + dataFormatada );
    }
}


// INICIA LISTVIEW

private ListView listLocais;
private TextView dataatual;

private String[] itens = {
        "Farmácia Santa Luzia", "Droga Raia", "Drogaria Droga Leste",
        "Drogaria Camila", "Drogaria Votufarma", "Farmácia Central", "Farmácia Brasil",
        "Drogarias FarMelhor", "Drogaria Bom Clima", "Drogaria São Paulo"
};

// TERMINA LISTVIEW


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela001);

    listLocais = findViewById(R.id.lst);

    //CRIAR ADAPTADOR
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1, itens);


    //ADICIONA O ADAPTADOR PARA A LISTA
    listLocais.setAdapter(adaptador);

    //ADICIONA UM CLIQUE NA LISTA
    listLocais.setOnItemClickListener

            (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                        View view, int i, long l) {


                    String valorSelecionado =
                            listLocais.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);


                    if (valorSelecionado == "Farmácia Santa Luzia")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://g.page/farmaciasantaluziavotuporanga?share");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Droga Raia")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/TfvtnJ2NVjn7NN4D6");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Drogaria Droga Leste")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/ux5DTEpTrEyTnp6F6");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Drogaria Camila")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/Ku8hTFX35c18HgHU7");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Drogaria Votufarma")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/bYmsYo81vZsnRU236");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Farmácia Central")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/ekddKUMgcP7j6QVGA");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Farmácia Brasil")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/z4EHdCqbyUgtyeAcA");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Drogarias FarMelhor")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/tgsUWsh15wxYv6PPA");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Drogaria Bom Clima")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/exbBuZ74LtPVCDGm8");
                    }

                    else if (valorSelecionado == "Drogaria São Paulo")
                    {
                        intent.putExtra("link","https://goo.gl/maps/HNmM2aGZysVoocBN7");
                    }

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


        // MOSTRA A DATA ATUAL
        dataatual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataatual);
        long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(date);
        dataatual.setText(dateString);
        // FIM DATA ATUAL


        // CRIAR COMPARAÇÃO PARA LISTAR DETERMINADAS FARMÁCIAS PELA DATA

}
```

Como criar uma situação para uns 3 dias apenas?

> **EDIT**: Há problemas com a captura e exibição dos itens.
>    a *class Farmacia* precisou ficar dentro do *TELA001*, pois, ao deixar em arquivo à parte, não era encontrada pelo Adapter:

```
public class TELA001 extends AppCompatActivity implements FarmaciaAdapter.OnFarmaciaItemClickListenerlistener {

private RecyclerView listLocais;
private TextView dataatual;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela001);

    listLocais = findViewById(R.id.rv_farmacias);
    dataatual  = findViewById(R.id.dataatual);

    List<Farmacia> farmacias = new ArrayList<>();

    // CRIAR NOVO OBJETO PARA CADA FARMACIA
    Farmacia exemplo = new Farmacia();
    exemplo.setNome("Farmácia Santa Luzia");
    exemplo.setUrl("https://g.page/farmaciasantaluziavotuporanga?share");

    Farmacia exemplo1 = new Farmacia();
    exemplo1.setNome("GOOGLE");
    exemplo1.setUrl("https://google.com");



    // DIA (INTEIRO)
    exemplo.setDia(24); // Dia exemplo

    // ADICIONAR TODOS OBJETOS NA LISTA
    farmacias.add(exemplo);
    farmacias.add(exemplo1);

    // CRIAR NOVO ADAPTER
    FarmaciaAdapter adapter = new FarmaciaAdapter();
    adapter.setOnFarmaciaItemClickListener(this); // CAPTURA O CLIQUE DO ITEM

    listLocais.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listLocais.setAdapter(adapter);

    // FILTRA A LISTA DAS FARMACIAS
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Date hoje = calendar.getTime();
    int dia   = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    List<Farmacia> novaLista = new ArrayList<>();

    // FILTRA FARMACIAS APENAS DO DIA SELECIONADO
    for (Farmacia obj : farmacias) {
    if (obj.getDia() == dia) novaLista.add(obj);
    }

    adapter.setData(novaLista);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
    String dateString = sdf.format(hoje);
    dataatual.setText(dateString);
}

    @Override
    public void onFarmaciaItemClick(@NonNull Farmacia item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("link", item.getUrl());
        startActivity(intent);
    }


class Farmacia {
    private String nome;
    private String url;
    private int dia;
    private int data;

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }
}
```

}

> **EDIT CONT**: Foi necessário criar o método para o *ItemClickListener*:

```
public class FarmaciaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FarmaciaAdapter.FarmaciaViewHolder> {


    private List<TELA001.Farmacia> data;
    private OnFarmaciaItemClickListener mListener;

    public void setOnFarmaciaItemClickListener(OnFarmaciaItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void setData(List<TELA001.Farmacia> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FarmaciaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new FarmaciaViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_farmacia, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FarmaciaViewHolder holder, int i) {
        holder.tvFarmaciaNome.setText(data.get(i).getNome());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
    }

public void setOnFarmaciaItemClickListener(TELA001 tela001) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Elemento " + getItemCount() + " clicado."); //FUNCIONANDO
}


public interface OnFarmaciaItemClickListenerlistener {
    void onFarmaciaItemClick(@NonNull TELA001.Farmacia item);
}



    class FarmaciaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvFarmaciaNome;

        FarmaciaViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            tvFarmaciaNome = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_farmacia_nome);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TELA001.Farmacia item = data.get(getAdapterPosition());

                    mListener.onFarmaciaItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnFarmaciaItemClickListener {
        void onFarmaciaItemClick(@NonNull TELA001.Farmacia item);
    }
}
```

[image: Itens não listados]

Comment: Você precisa exibir todas as farmácias filtradas pelo dias atual, certo?

Comment: Nao seria o caso de criar uma tabela num db sqlite ou outro qualquer de sua escolha e armazenar esses dados de forma que possa ser mutavel no sentido de cadastrar uma nova farmacia?  
Dai ficaria mais facil tambem filtrar os dados usando uma query sql por data, por nome, pelo que voce quiser.

Comment: @IvanSilva exato

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho Sim, ficaria mais fácil e mais profissional trabalhando com banco mesmo, porém como o app tem objetivos estudantis e o prazo está super apertado, não quis mudar toda a estrutura pra incluir banco com medo de piorar a situação...

Comment: Havia erros de digitação no meu código. Todos eles foram corrigidos. Percebi que você jogou todo o código dentro da `Activity`, daqui a pouco vai ficar bem confuso. Aconselho separar as coisas: crie a classe `Farmacia.java` e `FarmaciaAdapter.java`  em aquivos à parte.

Answer (score 0):

Uma ideia que pode dar um norte:

Usar um FOR que compare as datas, e se a comparação for verdadeira, exiba o conteudo da linha do list.
a variável auxiliar do for (utilizo na maioria das vezes "i") deve ser usada para verificar a linha do list.

encontrei conteudo a respeito no link: 
https://www.guj.com.br/t/como-comparar-datas/85294/10

data1.compareTo(date2)

lembrando que não domino a linguagem usada para desenvolvimento mobile mas a lógica pode ajudar. Dê os creditos ao Felipe caso conseguir ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar essa solução, você precisará usar um `Adapter` customizado mais uma `RecyclerView`.

> Faça um backup do seu código atual antes de fazer essas alterações.

1 - Substitua sua `ListView` por uma `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/rv_farmacias"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

2 - Crie um `layout` customizado para cada item da `RecyclerView`

> **Botão direito do mouse** em `layout`/ **New** / **Layout Resource file**

3 - Escolha `LinearLayout`, save ele como `item_farmacia.xml` adicione o seguinte `xml`

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_farmacia_nome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

4 - Crie uma nova classe e a nomeie como `FarmaciaAdapter` e adicione o seguinte código

```
public class FarmaciaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FarmaciaAdapter.FarmaciaViewHolder> {
    private List<Farmacia> data;
    private OnFarmaciaItemClickListener mListener;

    public void setOnFarmaciaItemClickListener(OnFarmaciaItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Farmacia> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BottomMenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new FarmaciaViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_farmacia, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FarmaciaViewHolder holder, int i) {
        holder.tvFarmaciaNome.setText(data.get(i).getNome());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
    }

   class FarmaciaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvFarmaciaNome;

        FarmaciaViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            tvFarmaciaNome = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_farmacia_nome);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Farmacia item = data.get(getAdapterPosition());

                    mListener.onFarmaciaItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnFarmaciaItemClickListener {
        void onFarmaciaItemClick(@NonNull Farmacia item);
    }
}
```

5 - Crie uma outra classe que sirva de modelo para a farmácia

```
public class Farmacia {
    private String nome;
    private String url;
    private int dia;

   public void setNome(String nome) {
      this.nome = nome;
   }

    public String getNome() {
      return nome;
   }

   public void setUrl(String url) {
      this.url = url;
   }

    public String getUrl() {
      return url;
   }

   public void setDia(int dia) {
      this.data = data;
   }

    public int getDia() {
      return dia;
   }
}
```

Todo esse trabalho é para que possamos trabalhar com objetos na lista e não simples `Strings`.

6 - Agora na sua `Activity`, faça o seguinte

```
public class TELA001 extends AppCompatActivity implements FarmaciaAdapter.OnFarmaciaItemClickListenerlistener {

     private RecyclerView listLocais;
     private TextView dataatual;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela001);

         listLocais = findViewById(R.id.rv_farmacias);
         dataatual  = findViewById(R.id.dataatual);

         List<Farmacia> farmacias = new ArrayList<>;

         // Crie um novo objeto para cada nova farmácia
         Farmacia exemplo = new Farmacia();
                  exemplo.setNome("Farmácia Santa Luzia");
                  exemplo.setUrl("https://g.page/farmaciasantaluziavotuporanga?share");
                  // O dia deverá ser um inteiro
                  exemplo.setDia(10); // Dia 10

         // Adicione todos os objetos nessa lista
         farmacias.add(exemplo);             

        // Vamos agora criar seu novo adapter
        FarmaciaAdapter adapter = new FarmaciaAdapter();
                        adapter.setOnFarmaciaItemClickListener(this); // Isso irá capturar o clique do item

        listLocais.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        listLocais.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Com todas as farmácias adicionadas a lista filtre  
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
         Date hoje = calendar.getTime();
         int dia   = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

         List<Farmacia> novaLista = new ArrayList<>();

         // Isso filtrará adicionando na nova lista apenas farmácias daquele dia
         // específica
         for (Farmacia obj : farmacias) {
             if (obj.getDia() == dia) novaLista.add(obj);
         }

        adapter.setData(novaLista);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(hoje);
        dataatual.setText(dateString);
     }

     @Override
     public void onFarmaciaItemClick(@NonNull Farmacia item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("link", item.getUrl());
        startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

Não testei esse código, então não sei se funciona na prática. Qualquer coisa é perguntar. Abraço!

Comment: Na parte 4 você usou expressão lambda, ainda não tinha usado no AndroidStudio... tentei seguir esse tutorial (https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=pt-BR#configuration) mas vários conflitos, oque fazer ?

Comment: Eu removi a expressão `lambda`, acredito que agora irá funcionar.

Comment: Reveja seu código para ter certeza que está igual ao meu.

Comment: Com a retirada da expressão - fluiu, no entanto não estou conseguindo exibir as farmácias, a ausência de algum código de erro complica mais

Comment: Talvez nenhuma farmácia esteja passando pela verificação `if (obj.getDia() == dia) novaLista.add(obj);`. Dá uma debugada aí com `Log.i()` e vê o que tá acontecendo